# Handling Large Images in Databases for Android Use

Tags: java, android, mysql, wamp

How do you handle large images in android? I have a table in mysql, and one of its columns contains large images(1-3mb) stored as BLOB. What I did is, I increased max_allowed_packet = 900M, also the `wait_timeout = 6000` because I got the error message `"MySQL server has gone away"`.

These images(blob datatype) is being downloaded, and stored in Android. I have heard that `Blob` is not advisable because it will consume a lot of space in the server having large and many images.

One thing I mind is that I will just store only the images path in the database instead of the image itself. Like `C:\image.jpg`, but I don't understand how this works in downloading the images. It is different from the real image stored. Real Image store vs Path.

How do you handle this kind of scenario wherein the images downloaded should be stored in the SD card. Also, I am not using web hosting and just my local server. Thanks

Comment: This may be off topic but i faced a similar situation in .NET. I'm telling this to you from my point of view,
Dont store images / others that take up load in your db, well just like you said try storing the url's of the images rather than storing than actual images in the db

There are sites like **imgur**, **photobucket**, **imageshack** that store your images privately which you can make use of for storing images and viewing them.

Comment: @MAD4RA  Thanks for the relate, hhmmm, I believe I can't use image hosting sites for storage as my requirement. I only use local database mysql server or wamp server.